# Call method from MultiView control on MasterPage

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, multiview, method-call

I'm trying to set a multiview control to the right view by calling a method from the code behind, which returns the value 0, but it won't return anything.

I have created a test method, which won't work:

**MasterPage.aspx**

```
<asp:MultiView ID="MultiView1" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex='<%# test() %>'>

                    <asp:View ID="LoginPnl" runat="server">
                        <a href="Login.aspx">Log ind</a>
                    </asp:View>

                    <asp:View ID="LogoutPnl" runat="server">
                        <a href="#">Min side</a>
                        <a href="#">Log ud</a>
                    </asp:View>
                </asp:MultiView>
```

**MasterPage.aspx.cs**

```
        using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class landrupdans : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected int test()
    {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

I hope someone can tell me, if it is possible at all to call methods from masterpages since it worked on another page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you need to do:

1. DataBind the MultiView.

<strike>2. Declare the method as public.</strike>

This code worked for me:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MultiView1.DataBind();
}

public int test()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ok, that worked even without setting the method to public. I just don't get, why i have to databind on the MasterPage, when the same code it works on another page without databind.

Comment: Yes, if the MultiView is inside any databound container, it will work without databinding.

Comment: ok, that make sense. On the other page it is inside a repeater.